# Not able to print multiple records in less time in perl script

Tags: perl

I have perl script which is used to display information date wise.
I fetch the data according to the date and keep it as flat file which has field seperator "AaBbCc".

file name would be

```
18-01-13_REPORT
17-01-13_REPORT
```

records would be

```
111 AaBbCc 2222 AaBbCc 3333 AaBbCc etc(each two lines forms a single record)
```

etc

Each file has more than 5000 records.Using my code I am able to print records successfully.
But it takes 15 minutes to print all the records.
Now I want to optimise the code to print those records in less time.

Please find my code

```
open (FILE,"$filename/$val_REPORT_DATE") 
    or die "Could not read from $filename, program halting.";
local $/ = undef; #get the whole file in to picture
while(<FILE>) {
    chomp $_;
    @fields = split('AaBbCc', $_);
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<$count ; ) {
        print "<tr><td>" . $fields[$i+0] .
              "</td><td>". $fields[$i+1] .
              "</td><td>". $fields[$i+2] .
              "</td><td>". $fields[$i+3] .
              "</td><td>". $fields[$i+4] .
              "</td><td>". $fields[$i+5] .
              "</td><td>". $fields[$i+6] .
                           $fields[$i+7] ."</td></tr>";
        $i = $i + 8;
    }
}
```

Please help me to print all records in short time to increase performance

Thanks in advance !!!
Vijay

Comment: That code takes 15 minutes to process 5k lines? There are a lot of bad practices there, but it shouldn't be anywhere near that slow on modern hardware.

Comment: Please let me know if u have any alternate solution for this using the same flat file format! Thanks

Comment: $count is number of lines in the flat file..if we have 5000 lines..then count will be 2500

Comment: So `$count` is NOT the number of lines in the file. It is half the number of lines in the file. How do you determine the number of lines in the file? That is not shown in this code.

Comment: "each two lines forms a single record"  Why? "...using the same flat file format..."  Why does it have to be the same?  As [jordanm](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1032785/jordanm) noted, there are bad practices in play here.  If a building's foundation is bad, you (and maybe others) will fight it all the way up--and perhaps evermore.  Who might inherit your coding?  Consider reformatting the data in your flat files (e.g., tab-delimited and one record per line), and then refactor your code using best practices.

Comment: Agree with Kenosis, this reeks of "quick hack". The record separator AaBbCc looks like someone took a string of letters that were unlikely to be used in any input. Use a proper format, such as csv instead.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few reasons why your code is slow:

1. The file format used is braindead.
2. For every element you look up in `@fields`, you perform an addition. While this wouldn't be overly costly in a low-level language, Perls Scalars are quite expensive.

   Here is one of the many parts from your opcode tree that do the array element lookups

   ```
   35               <2> aelem sK/2 ->36
   31                  <1> rv2av sKR/1 ->32        # get actual array
   30                      <#> gv[*fields] s ->31  # get global typeglob
   34                  <2> add[t63] sK/2 ->35      # create new scalar here
   -                       <1> ex-rv2sv sK/1 ->33  # get actual scalar
   32                         <#> gvsv[*i] s ->33  # get global typeglob
   33                      <$> const[IV 7] s ->34
   ```

   Compare this with an element lookup with lexical variables, and without the addition:

   ```
   c        <2> aelem sK/2 ->d
   a           <0> padav[@fields:47,49] sR ->b     # beautiful
   b           <0> padsv[$i:48,49] s ->c           # beautiful
   ```
3. There are a few best practices that could result in more performant code, e.g. using lexical variables with `my`. Global variables are looked up differently, and far slower (see above). Also, there is no need to slurp in the whole file at once. Why use that much memory if it can be done in constant space?

.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings; # every good script starts with these
use 5.010;

open my $file, "<", $filename or die qq(Couldn't open "$filename": $!):
until (eof $file) {
  # read two lines at a time
  my $line1 = <$file>;
  my $line2 = <$file> // die qq(uneven number of lines in "$filename");
  ...
}
```

Now we can fill in two possible solutions. Here is one that emphasizes dataflow programming (read from bottom upwards):

```
print
    "<tr>" . (
       join "" =>
       map  "<td>$_</td>",
       map  {chomp; split /AaBbCc/}
            ($line1, $line2)
    ) . "</tr>\n"
    ;
```

The same algorithm could be encoded as

```
chomp($line1, $line2);
my $string = "";
$string .= "<td>$_</td>" for split(/AaBbCc/, $line1), split(/AaBbCc/, $line2);
print "<tr>$string</tr>\n";
```

We could also abuse special variables:

```
chomp($line1, $line2);
my @fields = split(/AaBbCc/, $line1), split(/AaBbCc/, $line2);
local $" = "</td><td>"; # list seperator
print "<tr><td>@fields</td></tr>\n";
```

Or, without a named array:

```
chomp($line1, $line2);
local $" = "</td><td>";
print "<tr><td>@{[split(/AaBbCc/, $line1), split(/AaBbCc/, $line2)]}</td></tr>\n";
```

What I don't do is manually calculating indices, or unrolling loops.

Now while it isn't guaranteed that these variants will run faster, you have some material to experiment with. To *really* optimize your code, you should turn to the [Devel::NYTProf](https://metacpan.org/module/Devel%3a%3aNYTProf) profiler. It produces very detailed line-by-line reports, showing the number of times each statement was executed and how long this took on average.

---

Assuming that none of your fields includes tabs, this is a script to transform your data into a sane tab-seperated output:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings; use feature 'say';

# usage perl convert.pl filenames...

for my $filename (@ARGV) {
  open my $oldfile, "<", $filename       or die qq(Can't open "$filename": $!);
  open my $newfile, ">", "$filename.new" or die qq(Can't open "$filename.new": $!);
  until (eof $oldfile) {
     my $line1 = <$oldfile> // die qq(unexpected eof in "$filename");
     my $line2 = <$oldfile> // die qq(unexpected eof in "$filename": uneven number of lines);
     chomp( $line1, $line2 );
     my @fields = map {split /AaBbCc/, $_, 4} $line1, $line2;
     say $newfile join "\t" => @fields;
  }
  rename $filename       => "$filename.bak" or die qq(Can't back up "$filename");
  rename "$filename.new" => $filename       or die qq(Can't replace "$filename" with transformed data);
}
```

Comment: Hi Amon, Thanks a lot !It really helped me !!...But I am aware of Split in perl..Could you explain the use of "for split" and Please provide/suggest some good  links/materials to learn perl advanced concepts and programing techniques ...Thanks in advance

Comment: @user1990571 A number of conditional or looping operators can be used as *statement modifiers*. So `EXPR1 for EXPR2;` is the same as `for (EXPR2) { EXPR1 }`. The keywords `for` and `foreach` are interchangeable; you might like to think of the line as `do this stuff foreach split` instead. The [tag info for `perl`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/perl/info) lists links to tutorials and books, some of which are advanced.